# How to generate all possible mobile phone numbers in the world?

Tags: php, regex, expression, libphonenumber

So we set out to create and store every possible valid mobile phone number in the world, just because we can :)

How would you do that ?

Approximately 10 Billion numbers would be created, 5 Terra of MySQL storage used, all numbers stored in the DB would be unique.

So
1. We can extract the regular expression from [here](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php/tree/master/src/libphonenumber/data), expressions like :

```
'mobile' => 
  array (
    'NationalNumberPattern' => '
          1(?:
            5[0-25-9]\\d{8}|
            6[023]\\d{7,8}|
            7(?:
              [0-57-9]\\d?|
              6\\d
            )\\d{7}
          )
```

Then
2. We can use [this](https://github.com/icomefromthenet/ReverseRegex) for generating numbers, like so :

```
use ReverseRegex\Lexer;
use ReverseRegex\Random\SimpleRandom;
use ReverseRegex\Parser;
use ReverseRegex\Generator\Scope;

# load composer
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$lexer = new  Lexer('expression from above');
$gen   = new SimpleRandom(10007);
$result = '';

$parser = new Parser($lexer,new Scope(),new Scope());
$parser->parse()->getResult()->generate($result,$gen);

echo $result;
```

echoes are like this:

```
+33944631251+3613331251+3687539481+3612310548+3659429165+3689423986+33403300091+3646142500+3662480496+
```

3. We can double check (overkill), validate, parse and store:

   $phoneLib -> parse / format / isValidNumber ..

and

```
 function store ($nums_array){ /* Store in db */ }
```

Probably could get this work done with a couple of CPUs and multiproccessing in under a month.

But, got issues:
Reverse regex lib often ( 20% - 40% ) repeats numbers, generates too short or long numbers, generates numbers with ":".
On a time scale creating a unique number is getting harder and harder as possibilities narrow.
Disk consumption and speed of MySQL might not be the best solution here.

Given this should run on one server with one remote DB, what would be the optimal implementation ?

Comment: Are you working for a spam house or you just want to burn down the server? Anyhow, telephones are complex. Take the [North American Numbering Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan) for example. There are hypothetically 10 billion numbers in the form of `xxx-xxx-xxxx`, but then `000-000-0000` isn't valid and neither is `xxx-x11-xxxx`. You would have to code all that in, for 200+ countries

Comment: libphonenumber ( first link ) mapped all possible numbers with expressions. 534 files with patterns, 2 files per country.

Comment: You need to remove special characters from the regexes themselves, then combine them into one.  This isn't easy.

Comment: @QuestionC like so :
          1(?5[0-25-9]\\d{8}|6[023]\\d{7,8}|7(?[0-57-9]\\d?|6\\d)\\d{7})
?